# Performance of assigning a simple lambda expression or a local function to a delegate

Tags: c#, lambda, c#-7.0

When using a very simple expression as key to create an ILookup with [`Enumerable.ToLookup<TSource, TKey> Method (IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073(v=vs.110).aspx) I can use a lambda expression:

```
var lk = myItems.ToLookup((x) => x.Name);
```

or a local function:

```
var lk = myItems.ToLookup(ByName);

string ByName(MyClass x)
{
     return x.Name;
}
```

I'm curious if there is a difference in this simple case.

In [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949214/814206) to [Local function vs Lambda C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40943117/814206) SO user [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) gives a good argument why –in general– local functions are preferable to lambdas.

An important point is the difference in performance:

> When creating a lambda, a delegate has to be created, which is an unnecessary allocation in this case. Local functions are really just functions, no delegates are necessary.

But since we pass it to `ToLookup()` a delegate is created anyway.  Is there still a difference in performance?
I can imagine that the compiler has to create a fresh delegate lambda for each invocation of myItems.ToLookup, whereas there only needs to be a single delegate instance for the local method; is this true?

A second point of difference in performance in [svick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40949214/814206) is the capturing of variables and the creation of closures:

> Also, local functions are more efficient with capturing local variables: lambdas usually capture variables into a class, while local functions can use a struct (passed using ref), which again avoids an allocation.

However, since the expression does not use variables from the outer scope, there does not have to be a closure as [stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9591622/814206) by [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey) and [expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9592254/814206) by [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) in answer to [Are Lambda expressions in C# closures?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9591476/814206):

> A lambda may be implemented using a closure, but it is not itself necessarily a closure.  — [Reed Copsey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/65358/reed-copsey)
>   [...]
>   a function that can be treated as an object is just a delegate. What makes a lambda a closure is that it captures its outer variables. — [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert)

This is somewhat contradicted [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) himself is his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41131740/814206) to [Assigning local functions to delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41129822/814206) [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) explains a local function as a named lambda:

> A local function is basically just a lambda with an associated name.

But this is at a level of lesser technical detail and for delegates of lambda's/local functions that *do* capture outer scope variables.

This simple expression is not recursive, not generic, and not an iterator.  And which looks better is a matter of opinion.
So, are there any differences in performance (or otherwise) between simple not capturing, non recursive, non generic, and non iterator lambda expressions and local functions?

Comment: See this answer from John Skeet https://stackoverflow.com/q/49299443/2499773

Comment: My intention in the last quoted answer was simply to say that if there's a way to make a function in the form of a lambda, then there is also a way to make a logically identical local function. I wasn't intending to imply that the implementation details were the same. Apologies if that was confusing. I've updated the text in the linked answer to hopefully be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With the current version of the compiler (Roslyn 2.8.0), the version with lambda is more efficient, because it caches the delegate.

Looking at [the IL of code that has your two samples in separate methods](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYBuAWACh8jiAWC6wkgOgBk0A7AR0apwBMBAMJUA3lQJSidAmwhhgAEwgAKEgGYAPAFkAnsIzQoAPgJg9ASXhgoASknSJlaa4IA3CAgIYA1gQBecysbKBYAFQB7NkjI3wBXAAdVVQAPO0CzVJYAOQU4O0ZXAF9HKTKZOUiAYwgMHABWGDRIznVibX1DYzMLazhbBxcnCtdPbz9A4P7bCOjYhOSAIT08sAK+YbdaQhW1uFUuoygoAnTRka3t1xwAdjPc/KLr0qvX1/4hI+NxCpwNHYEfYEMQEADmcBgpAI7yAA=), it's effectively:

```
sealed class HelperClass
{
    public static readonly HelperClass Instance = new HelperClass();

    public static Func<MyClass, string> CachedDelegate;

    internal string LambdaByName(MyClass x)
    {
        return x.Name;
    }

    internal string LocalFunctionByName(MyClass x)
    {
        return x.Name;
    }
}

void Lambda(IEnumerable<MyClass> myItems)
{
    var lk = myItems.ToLookup(HelperClass.CachedDelegate ??
        (HelperClass.CachedDelegate =
            new Func<MyClass, string>(HelperClass.Instance.LambdaByName)));
}

void LocalFunction(IEnumerable<MyClass> myItems)
{
    var lk = myItems.ToLookup(
        new Func<MyClass, string>(HelperClass.Instance.LocalFunctionByName)));
}
```

Notice how `Lambda` allocates the delegate only once and uses a cached delegate afterwards, while `LocalFunction` allocates the delegate every time. This makes `Lambda` more efficient in this specific case.

Though there is [a proposal on GitHub to change the compiler to make `LocalFunction` as efficient as `Lambda`](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5835).